# How to get multiple search results from one document

Tags: php, python, pdf, elasticsearch

I want to search through multiple pdf files and have the search result give me multiple results for each pdf file.

How do I get one result from each chapter that contains the words in the search?

Let's say I want to search for recipes that contain eggs:
There could be multiple recipes that contain eggs in one document, but when I use google advanced search I only get one result for each pdf document.

My objective is to collect multiple pdf files on a web page and use a search functionality to find all sections containing the word in the search.

Comment: You want to do it using ES?

Comment: Your book becomes index and each recipe becomes a document in ES, that is one approach

Comment: Don't have to be elastic search. I am open to suggestions on all possible solutions to this problem, no matter what the technology/software is used to solve this.